# Are varied banners loaded at each site visit counter-productive for Magento because of caching?

Tags: cache

I have a customer that would like a different banners loaded for each visit to a page.  They like how teehanlax.com loads something different each time. They like the idea of a new experience each time.  They would like it to rotate between five different scenes.

Does Magento caching kill that experience?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you use it.
If the page loads the banner from the server then caching will kill your feature.

If it loads a banner making an ajax request you can remove from cache that request only and everything should work.

If you don't have a large number of banners (like you said...5) then I guess you can load all the banners at once, out them in a json and randomize them through javascript. I think this solves the problem nicely. You can cache the page with the banners retrieved from the db and the display is processed on the client side using js.